# QGIS raster calculator using second raster to set value in first

Tags: qgis-3, raster-calculator

I have two rasters.  ras1@1 has values from 1-50, ras2@1 has values 0 and 1.  I want to convert values from ras1@1 >= 4 to 1, except where ras2@1 = 1, which I want to set to 0.  I cannot work out how to do this.  I was thinking something like:

`(ras@1 >= 4 AND ras2@1 = 0) * 1`

or

`((ras1@1 >= 4) * 1) - ras2@1`

but neither seem to return what I want.  Everything I have tried seems to return just ras2@1 = 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try;

```
(((ras1@1 - 1) * (ras1@1 < 4)) + 1) * (1 - ras2@1)
```

I don't know how to explain this clearly; hope the below image can help -
[image]

- If cells in ras1@1 are any of 1, 2, 3: `((ras1@1 - 1) * (ras1@1 < 4)) + 1` returns 1, 2, 3, while 4 or greater figures become 1.
- `(1-ras2@1)` will invert 0/1.